# MacBook Pro stop charging at 99%

Tags: battery

Most of the time my MacBook Pro stop charging at 99%. But when I check the battery status it says battery is charged. My battery cycles is around 500. Does it means I needs a new battery or it is something else? Thanks.

I am using Mid 2012 MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and the reason to it is so as to prolong the overall life of the battery. You can see more information [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204054).